# In application script hosting. How does tryfsharp.org work?

Tags: f#

I am interested in the ability to have F# scripting within my app.

Having something like [tryfsharp.org](http://tryfsharp.org/Create) would be great, specifically the Intellisense capability.  Is any of this available on Github somewhere?  How does this work?

Comment: Not sure if this is the real tryfsharp, but Google yielded [this](https://github.com/timrobinson/try-fsharp)

Comment: It's not.  That is based on http://tryfs.net  The above site is from MS research.

Comment: His question is poorly worded, but it amounts to: "how do I enable scripting with F# in my application."

Comment: G’day. I'm one of the developers of Tsunami IDE which is intended to enable people to add F# scripting to their applications with full Intellisense capability. We’ve not released yet I but would be interested in hearing more about what you are looking for to make sure we are able to meet your needs.

Comment: @moloneymb I watched one of the Tsunami videos, good stuff.  I'm interested in knowing how this integrates with everything else.  Specifically, how is the code assembled and accessible once a user saves what they have done.  Would it be possible to have this integrated so that the code which is written is plugged in as the body to a function.  Like a delegates handler.

Comment: @Dave Thanks :) You probably would not want to do what I did with Tsunami – which was fork the compiler to add a number of features.  If you’re doing this yourself TryFS.Net and Pit approaches are probably the best places to start.

Comment: @moloneymb Yes have no desire to do that.  But wouldn't mind to see what you guys have to offer as an end to end solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Short answer**

The code used for the first cut of TryFSharp with F# 2, which includes Intellisense support, is available as a [code drop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/11/15/updates-to-the-august-2011-f-2-0-compiler-code-drop.aspx). As an example Rob Pickering built an online editor for [Undertone](http://strangelights.com/blog/archive/2012/01/27/undertone-ndash-programmable-music-in-f.aspx) with it. I suspect the code used on the current TryFSharp site which uses F# 3 will appear in time.

TryFSharp uses Silverlight to host the F# compiler in the client's browser (F# is written in F#). It is also possible to call an instance of the F# compiler running on the server from the browser on demand, which is an approach taken by [TryFs.Net](http://tryfs.net/) and [Pit](https://github.com/fsharp/pitfw).

**Longer answer**

There are two sides to scripting:

1. Editing
2. Execution

F# already supports editing and execution of (.fsx) [script files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/09/12/scripting-in-f.aspx) via [F# Interactive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx).

**Editing F# Code**

There's no shortage of external editors for F# code:

- [Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/09/12/announcing-the-release-of-f-tools-for-visual-studio-express-2012-for-web.aspx)
- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD)
- [Xamarin Studio](http://xamarin.com/studio)
- [Emacs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2013/01/19/f-emacs-integration.aspx)
- [Vim](https://github.com/timrobinson/fsharp-vim)
- [TryFSharp](http://www.tryfsharp.org/)
- [F# Notebook](https://fsnotebook.net)

The editor support for Xamarin Studio, Emacs and Vim is based on the open source [F# Bindings](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding) project, which provides code completion.
SharpDevelop uses the open source [AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit) and includes syntax highlighting for F#. You can use AvalonEdit in your own projects, for example the open source [Refunctor](http://refunctor.codeplex.com/) project uses it to provide F# editing inside Reflector.

There are also a couple of new editors for F# on the horizon:

- [Cloud Sharper](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10200294287900993&set=vb.189105887856115&type=2&theater) - web based F# IDE
- [Tsumani IDE](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTYyqC9O4DBGfdsjaLVp7cg) - embedded editor for Excel, Hadoop, etc.

AvalonEdit is a good place to start for a desktop based embedded editor. Once you've chosen an editor environment then you need to choose between simple syntax highlighting or more advanced integration using F# Bindings. If you suspect people will use an external editor then syntax highlighting may be sufficient.

Bring your own editor is probably the easiest place to start which just leaves execution.

**Executing F# Code**

Options for executing F# code:

- [F# CodeDOM](https://twitter.com/ptrelford/status/309680845403353088/photo/1) from the [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/)
- F# Compiler via the F# compiler code drop or invoking [fsi.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx)

Compiling a snippet with the F# CodeDOM:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom
open System.CodeDom.Compiler

let compile snippet =
    use provider = new FSharpCodeProvider()
    let options = CompilerParameters(GenerateInMemory=true)
    provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, [|snippet|])

let snippet = """
module Snippet
let x = 1
"""
let results = compile snippet
```