# "CompileAssemblyFromSource" in f# powerPack codeDom

Tags: dynamic, f#, codedom, powerpack, compileassemblyfromsource

I am trying to get going a basic program to dynamically compile and run f# code. I am trying to run the following code:

```
open System 
open System.CodeDom.Compiler 
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom 

// Our (very simple) code string consisting of just one function: unit -> string 
let codeString =
"module Synthetic.Code\n    let syntheticFunction() = \"I've been compiled on the      fly!\""
// Assembly path to keep compiled code
let synthAssemblyPath = "synthetic.dll"

let CompileFSharpCode(codeString, synthAssemblyPath) =
    use provider = new FSharpCodeProvider() 
    let options = CompilerParameters([||], synthAssemblyPath) 
    let result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource( options, [|codeString|] ) 
    // If we missed anything, let compiler show us what's the problem
    if result.Errors.Count <> 0 then 
        for i = 0 to result.Errors.Count - 1 do
            printfn "%A" (result.Errors.Item(i).ErrorText)
    result.Errors.Count = 0

if CompileFSharpCode(codeString, synthAssemblyPath) then
    let synthAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(synthAssemblyPath) 
    let synthMethod  =      synthAssembly.GetType("Synthetic.Code").GetMethod("syntheticFunction") 
    printfn "Success: %A" (synthMethod.Invoke(null, null))
else
    failwith "Compilation failed"
```

from this site: http://infsharpmajor.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/how-to-dynamically-synthesize-executable-f-code-from-text/

The issue I am having is with the following line:

```
let result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource( options, [|codeString|] )
```

Where I get the exception: `The System cannot find the file specified.`

I have included the required references `Fsharp.compiler.codeDom.dll` and `Fsharp.compiler.dll` and I am not sure what else could be there issue. I am currently trying to get the dll source code for `CodeDom` off of codeplex and step through it but it would save me a lot of headache if somebody is able to see some issue I am overlooking.

Thank you for your time,
-Alper

Comment: The following link includes minimal code for in memory compilation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313404/in-application-script-hosting-how-does-tryfsharp-org-work

Comment: This issue seems related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733415/fsharp-core-sigdata-not-found-alongside-fsharp-core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underneath the F# PowerPack's CodeDOM implementation uses the F# compiler to generate code, which means it needs a way to find the compiler and related metadata.

First off you may need to copy the [FSharp.Core.sigdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733415/fsharp-core-sigdata-not-found-alongside-fsharp-core) file to your bin folder (the metadata). You may also need to add the F# compiler (fsc.exe) to your path or alternatively just copy it into your bin folder (fsc.exe is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0). Atleast this worked for me on my Windows 8 machine with Visual Studio 2012 installed.